# How to Properly Import JS Objects in Odoo v16: Modifying Visibility in POS Popup

Tags: odoo-16

I'm currently working on a module aimed at modifying the visibility of specific elements within the close POS popup for Odoo v16. My strategy involves creating a user group that can access these elements. As part of this, I need to incorporate this information into the getClosePosInfo() function within the PosGlobalState class when the popup is rendered.
Here's a snippet of my JavaScript file:

```
var models = require('point_of_sale.models');
var PosModel = models.PosModel;
var CustomPosGlobalState = PosModel.include({
});
```

However, upon starting the POS session, I encounter the following error:

`PosModel is undefined TypeError: PosModel is undefined` 
I'm seeking guidance on understanding what might be causing this issue  and if there's an alternative approach you could recommend.